# Creating a distribution from simulated samples in matrix format

Tags: r, matrix, simulation

I have a matrix of statistics, called T_{i,j}. I then simulated 1000 samples. I would like to use the 1000 samples to build a distribution and then calculate a p-value for my observed T_{i,j}.

A sample T_{i,j} matrix looks like this:

```
         V12         V13        V22        V23       V117       V146
V12  0.009900990 0.008281829 0.01490863 0.01548161 0.01342882 0.01287918
V13  0.008281829 0.031250000 0.04367911 0.04597988 0.03876530 0.03182001
V22  0.014908629 0.043679113 0.50000000 0.36522152 0.45404452 0.09666729
V23  0.015481606 0.045979882 0.36522152 0.50000000 0.47827009 0.10272845
V117 0.013428819 0.038765301 0.45404452 0.47827009 0.50000000 0.09810254
V146 0.012879176 0.031820011 0.09666729 0.10272845 0.09810254 0.09090909
```

What I would like to do is to easily get p-values for each possible entry. In the above matrix there are 21 separate statistics as everything below the diagonal is just the transpose of everything above.

I realize I can go in with for loops to look at each (i,j) entry over all the samples, sort them and then figure out where my observed lies, but I was wondering perhaps there is an easier R way to do it?

I have put a sample set of data here (data outputted via dput): 
http://temp-share.com/show/3YgF5Ww2x

Comment: What statistics are in your matrix of statistics?

Comment: So each i,j element is a statistic that relates how close mutations occur in a protein. It's not from a known distribution, as I created the statistic (thinking perhaps it might be informative). I then simulate a lot of potential protein mutations to get a distribution for my statistic.

Comment: Is your statistic univariate or multivariate? In the first case, R can estimate the empirical density easily, using optimal kernels. This is a very well know problem in non-parametric statistics. By the way, if the idioms "kernel", "empirical density", "epanechnikov" seem strangers for you, I suggest reading something on density estimation before you continue. Here's a basic link: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)]

Comment: No, I'm familiar with kernels. Perhaps I was unclear. Each i,j element is a statistic. It is a function distance and counts of mutations (so in that case I suppose it's multivariate). Also, under the null, I can easily simulate from the distribution. To use a kernel, I would need several observations of each statistic, here I have many statistics, but exactly one observation of each.

Comment: I think I got it. So you have a matrix-like statistic, whose null distribution you want to approximate via a monte carlo sampling. OK. But how about the acceptance region? In the answer below, ndoogan treats each entry in the matrix as an observable, thus ignoring any correlation structure. If you want a single p-value for you entire observed matrix, then you need to define the criteria under which a given matrix is accepted or rejected under the null hypothesis. Then it'll be straightforward to adapt ndoogan's code to get an approximate p-value.

Comment: Good point, @Ferdinand.kraft. However, the user does specify he/she is looking for "p-values for each possible entry." Incidentally, if a single p-value is desired, accounting for correlation, a Mahalanobis distance test could be useful.

Comment: @ndoogan, you're right. I didn't even notice the user asked for separated p-values. Your response is perfect, I upvoted it actually. But I still suspect a single test would be more adequate for this kind of data.

Comment: Hi, yes, each element on the diagonal and above is a separate statistical test representing whether two AA with mutations are closer together than by chance. Thus, if I look at the whole matrix at once, I am looking at whether the entire protein somehow has mutations closer together, not just pairs of AA. But thanks for the link about Mahalanobis distance :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If LT is a list of some number of null hypothesis simulated matrices like T, and you want to do a one-tailed test (say, above), then you can count the number of times each element of T fell above or equal to the associated value in the simulation. I'm using reduce to sum the 1000 matrices returned from the lapply.

```
ct <- Reduce("+", lapply(LT,function(x) x >= T))
```

The result is a matrix of the same size as T that counts (ct) the number of times the elements of T were exceeded by (or were equal to) the corresponding elements of the matrices in LT. Divide this matrix by the simulation sample size (number of simulations).

```
p <- ct / length(LT)
```

p is a matrix of approximate p values representing the probability that a null hypothesis simulation is at least as extreme (on the upper end) as the observed data. If any p < alpha, then you might say the null hypothesis is a poor model in the case of the specific element of the observation.

Adjust the test "x >= T" to run the test you actually want to run, which could be a two-sided test.

Comment: Wouldn't the test actually be the opposite from the code in the reduce statement? Consider the following: Say my result is significant when T_{1,1} <= x. Say that my observed T_{1,1} = 0.1, and I have 3 entries in the 1,1 position of LT: 0.2,0.3, 0.4. That means, that for the 1,1 entry I would have a ct value of 3 and a p-value of 1. However, in reality, my p-value is between 0 and 1/3. Thus if T>=x, I am testing significance for small values of T and when T<=x, I am testing significance for large values of T. Assuming I understand the code correctly!

Comment: You're right. I edited the answer to say 'p <- 1 - ct / length(LT)'.

Comment: Ultimately, though, you can modify the procedure to test whatever makes sense in your circumstance.

Comment: upon further review, I noticed more inconsistencies in the answer. I modified it (actually to @user1357015 's specifications) to make more sense. The answer is still essentially the same.